# Function parameter within a string

Tags: r

I would like to put a parameter within a string in order to import a file with this function:

```
import_df <- function(df) {
  df <- read_xpt(
    file = "C:\\Folder\\Sub1\\Sub2\\df.xpt"
  )
  return(df)
}

import_df(ds1)
```

Problem is each time I get this message: Error: 'C:\folder\Sub1\Sub2\df.xpt' does not exists.
It does not consider "df" as "ds1" in the file path. How can I do it with a R function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ll have the same issue with *any* variable, not just function parameters. A string literal is fundamentally different from code. If it weren’t, how would R be supposed to know that you intend `df` to be a variable? Why not also `C`, `Folder`, `Sub1`, `Sub2` and `xpt`?

You’ll need to tell R to construct your string from different parts. There are different ways of doing this; the most basic is `paste0`:

```
paste0("C:\\Folder\\Sub1\\Sub2\\", df, ".xpt")
```

Another frequently used way is `sprintf`, which is mainly useful for people who are familiar with other languages, such as C. Otherwise, you could install the package ‘[glue](https://glue.tidyverse.org/index.html)’ and use the `glue` function to *interpolate* your variable:

```
glue("C:\\Folder\\Sub1\\Sub2\\{df}.xpt")
```

Comment: Hello, sorry it did not work. Tried both paste0 and glue but the output always says my file is not found (and i'm sure it's in the right file path). I have this code: read_xpt(file = glue(...)) (the same with paste0).

Comment: @Alox The code definitely works, it’s pretty hard to diagnose what might go wrong. But chances are that the file path is indeed wrong, i.e. the file doesn’t actually exist. try printing the path before passing it to `read_xpt`: `message(glue(…))`, and make sure that that exact path does actually exist. Also, it’s easy to get confused with double backslashes. Try using forward slashes instead, i.e. use `/` instead of ` \\ ` everywhere in the path.

Comment: Alright I found it... I need to get my parameter between quotes when I call the function. The function running correctly know, except I'm not getting the object at the end. I'm gonna work on it, but still this issue is solved thanks to you Konrad Rudolph and also NicolasH2.

Answer (score 0):

you need the `paste0` command.

```r
file = paste0("C:\\Folder\\Sub1\\Sub2\\", df, ".xpt")
```

Basically, everything inside the brackets will be pasted together. A similar command is `paste` which will automatically introduce a space between the concatenated strings or whatever you tell it with the `sep` arguement.